# Is the Rayleigh Jean Formula an approximation of a poisson distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I'm a senior physics major planning to pursue a PhD. I'm finally taking my Thermo/Stat Mech course and I realized that the Poisson distribution looks similar to the curve of the Rayleigh-Jean Formula for thermal radiation. Since the formula includes $\lambda^{-4}$, it has never sat well with my physical intuition because  powers of $4$ are not common. Is there a better or more modern theory that explains the behavior of thermal radiation?

Comment: One man's fish is another man's poisson.

Comment: Seriously, I think the rayleigh-jeans formula has that fourth-power dependence not because the fundamental physics goes like that but because it has two separate 2nd-power terms multiplied together in it.

Comment: You have physical intuition about powers of 4? How does that work?

Comment: If you are looking for other examples of powers of four, see for example, the Stefan–Boltzmann law, scalar field theory with quartic interaction, the power series expansion of any even function beyond two terms, etc.

Comment: @hft, I seem to remember the derivation from long ago but I could be wrong.  Now I'll have to look this up!

Answer (score 1):

It's got nothing to do with a Poisson distribution. The density in $\lambda$ goes as $\lambda^{-d-1}$ if space is $d$-dimensional. The analogous result for $\omega$ is $\omega^{d-1}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law#Comparison_to_Planck%27s_law) for an explanation in terms of subsequent theory.

Answer (score 1):

The Rayleigh-Jeans Law
$$
{\displaystyle B_{\lambda }(T)={\frac {2ck_{\mathrm {B} }T}{\lambda ^{4}}},}
$$
is an approximation to Planck's Law
$${\displaystyle B_{\lambda }(T)={\frac {2hc^{2}}{\lambda ^{5}}}~{\frac {1}{e^{\frac {hc}{\lambda k_{\mathrm {B} }T}}-1}},}
$$
when the exponent
$$
{\frac {hc}{\lambda k_{\mathrm {B} }T}<< 1}
$$
This is the long wavelength region of the Planck spectrum.  It has nothing to do with a Poisson distribution.